# scope of variables in an ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-variables

I am using the fairly antiquated code behind techniques on a asp.net vb project. I have a series of panels that I want to initialise and use, but I find that I have to keep defining them every time I want to use them in a sub.

Here is what I mean

```
Partial Class Main_Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
        Dim attendedPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("attendedPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendPanel")
        Dim groupOnePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupOnePanel")
        Dim groupTwoPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupTwoPanel")
        Dim groupThreePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupThreePanel")
        Dim finishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("finishPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendFinishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendFinishPanel")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub attendedPanelClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'test if attended checkbox is ticked
        Dim attendedCheckbox As CheckBox
        attendedCheckbox = Me.FormView1.FindControl("AttendedOrFTACheckBox")
        If attendedCheckbox.Checked Then
            showGroupOne()
        Else
            showDidNotAttend()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub showDidNotAttend()
        Dim attendedPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("attendedPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendPanel")
        Dim groupOnePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupOnePanel")
        Dim groupTwoPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupTwoPanel")
        Dim groupThreePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupThreePanel")
        Dim finishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("finishPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendFinishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendFinishPanel")

        attendedPanel.Visible = False
        didNotAttendPanel.Visible = True
        groupOnePanel.Visible = False
        groupTwoPanel.Visible = False
        groupThreePanel.Visible = False
        finishPanel.Visible = False
        didNotAttendFinishPanel.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Public Sub showGroupOne()
        Dim attendedPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("attendedPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendPanel")
        Dim groupOnePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupOnePanel")
        Dim groupTwoPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupTwoPanel")
        Dim groupThreePanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupThreePanel")
        Dim finishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("finishPanel")
        Dim didNotAttendFinishPanel As Panel = Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendFinishPanel")

        attendedPanel.Visible = False
        didNotAttendPanel.Visible = False
        groupOnePanel.Visible = True
        groupTwoPanel.Visible = False
        groupThreePanel.Visible = False
        finishPanel.Visible = False
        didNotAttendFinishPanel.Visible = False

    End Sub
```

So really what I need is a way to take the Dim statements and put them in a function of their own.

e.g.

```
 sub setDims()
  'set the panels up here
 end sub
```

So could someone tell me what I'm doing so wrong here please?

Comment: It's not clear what this means `set the panels up here`

Comment: If I understand you correctly: Create global variables for the panels and in `SetDims` you put the `FindControl` statements. Everywhere where you now have those DIM-statements, you just have to call `SetDims()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either global variables, a helper function that takes Booleans or just skip the variable declaration completely:

```
Public Sub showDidNotAttend()
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("attendedPanel").Visible = False
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendPanel").Visible = False
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupOnePanel").Visible = True
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupTwoPanel").Visible = False
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("groupThreePanel").Visible = False
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("finishPanel").Visible = False
    Me.FormView1.FindControl("didNotAttendFinishPanel").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks - yeah, I initialised them outside of the functions and made a sub to set them.